# Statistical test to verify if a population has a average of k times another

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

Consider the situation where there are 2 positive distributions with unknown expected values $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$,

We have samples $S_1 = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ and $S_2 = \{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$.

We would like to use a statistical test under the null hypothesis: $\mu_1 = k \times \mu_2$.

Do you know what kind of test should we use?

Comment: I assume that you looking for a test with a specific value of $k$ in mind. Are there any assumptions about the underlying distributions, or about the variances of $S_1$ and $S_2$?

Comment: O don't have an assumption about the distributions ir variances. Do you know a test in this framework that uses an assumption that is not mentioned above?

Comment: I notice you have the same sample size for both samples. Is this because there's some pairing or are the samples independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your null is that the distributions are the same i.e. that $F_1(x) = F_2(x k)$ when you could perhaps do a permutation test: multiply the observations in sample 2 by $k$ ($x_{2i}^*=kx_{2i},\,i=1,2,...,n$ and then test whether they have the same mean, because under the null, the set of $kx_{2i}$ and $x_{1j}$ would be exchangeable.

If you are additionally interested specifically in a pure scale shift alternative (and want an easily-obtained interval for it) you might divide the first sample through by $k$ (or multiply the second by $k$), take logs and look at a location shift (whether a permutation test or a rank based test like the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney), before backtransforming the interval

If you have a suitable parametric assumption, using that information will generally be advantageous (power-wise), if the assumption is true or very nearly true.

Note that failure to reject doesn't mean the multiplier *is* $k$. You can't verify that; you might consider whether an equivalence test comes nearer to what you need in that case.